# How can I join a string repeatedly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to do something like:

```
string s1 set to null
s2: "abc"

repeat 10 times

s1=s1+s2
```

How can I do this in objective-c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this suitable?:

```
NSMutableString *s1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString *s2 = @"abc";

for(NSInteger idx = 0; idx < 10; ++idx) {
   [s1 appendString:s2];
}

...

[s1 release];
```

Comment: +1. But in spirit of obj-c memory management rules and the bugs we see here so often, maybe better call `[NSMutableString stringWithString:@""]` to get an autoreleased string.

Comment: Or just `[NSMutableString string]`.

Answer (score 0):

Although @thatsdisgusting gave a perfect answer, here's a shortcut:

```
NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
NSString *pad = @"abc";
NSString *ret = [a stringByPaddingToLength:10*[pad length] withString:pad
                                                           startingAtIndex:0];
```

abusing `stringByPaddingToLength`.